# Removing console.logs in development version of React / Redux / MERN-stack application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, console.log

I have two console-logging issues I am trying to resolve here. One is simpler and i can simply comment out a few lines of code to bandaid the problem, but I'd like to ask both here.

First, for redux, in my `store.js` file I use `redux-logger` to console.log in production the different actions. Here is my `store.js` file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== `prod`) {
    const { logger } = require(`redux-logger`);
    middleware.push(logger);
}

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

Unfortunately, the `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !==`prod`) {` condition is not working, as the `redux-logger` outputs are showing up in the version of my app that I deploy on my EC2 instance.

Second, I would like to suppress all `console.logs` in general in EC2 instance dev version. I have installed this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console - and I created a `.babelrc` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
        }
    }
}
```

However, even with the library installed and the `.babelrc` file created, the console.logs appear in the dev version of the app.

Any help with how I can go about debugging each of these problems would be greatly appreciated. For the time being, I am simply commenting out the `redux-logger` lines of code in the store to remove the logger's output, but I have no way of easily hiding the other console.logs (beyond commenting them out across all of the different components of my app).

**Edit**: please let me know if sharing any of the other app files, or looking up version numbers for certain libraries, will help with this!

Thanks!

Comment: Few thoughts: 1) If you are using the react build `process.env.NODE_ENV` is usually set to `production`, not `prod`. Try logging the value and seeing what it is? 2) The babel transform (I'm guessing) goes through your code and removes any instances of `console.log` but it may not be able to manage that for `redux-logger` calls. Just a guess in the dark but I hope it helps.

Comment: You are right that it is production, not prod. It looks like this should resolve the redux-logger issue.

Comment: The issue I'm having with the babel transform is that it's not working at all - not even for the ordinary `console.logs` throughout the code